# How can I modify the class for a button in a django widget form?

Tags: django, forms, widget

I'm trying to set the class for a form widget. I have:

```
<form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.input.label_tag }} {{ form.input.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.input.errors }}
            {{ form.input }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.itinerary.label_tag }} {{ form.itinerary.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.itinerary.errors }}
            {{ form.itinerary }}
        </p>
        <p><input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

and it looks like [image]

I attempted to use django tweak tools when I tried googling to find a solution for my problem. I modified the code to be like this too see how it would change:

```
<form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% load widget_tweaks %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.input.label_tag }} {{ form.input.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.input.errors }}
            {{ form.input }}
            {% render_field form.input class="button" %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.itinerary.label_tag }} {{ form.itinerary.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.itinerary.errors }}
            {{ form.itinerary }}
        </p>
        <p><input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>
```

and that looks like [image]

It applies the class to the whole widget, and it turns the whole widget into a button.

So how can I apply the class to just the button in the widget?

Answer (score 1):

So there really isn't an easy way to add a class to a form element.

The way I was able to solve this was to create a custom template tag.

If you interested in learning more about this you can visit the following link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/

What I did was create a directory under the app directory called templatetags.

Make sure you have an `__init__.py` in this directory, and then create another file. I named mine template_helper.py

```
    # template_helper.py
    from django import template
    from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict

    register = template.Library()

    @register.filter(name='addcss')
    def addcss(field, css):
       return field.as_widget(attrs={"class":css})
```

In the actual template you would just have to first load the template_helper via: `{% load template_helper %}` then add the `{{ form_element|addcss:"button" }}`

> You'll want to somehow check with the template tags `{% if ... %}` to
>   make sure you only apply the class to the button if you only want to
>   apply the class to the button.

```
    {% load template_helper %}
    <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.input.label_tag }} {{ form.input.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.input.errors }}
            {% for field in form.input %}
                {{ field|addcss:"button" }}
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.itinerary.label_tag }} {{ form.itinerary.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.itinerary.errors }}
            {{ form.itinerary }}
        </p>
        <p><input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: So I did everything here, and it still ended up applying the css to the whole widget, not just the button that says "Choose file" which is what I want it to apply to. It looks just like the rendered field in the second picture I put.

Comment: Try looping through your form elements and adding the class to the button specifically. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to [this](http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/), it worked well for what I was trying to do. And now it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/a/gI0PL)

Comment: Just curious if you are still working on this part, if you do a `{% if 'type="file"' in field %}{{ field|addcss:"button" }}{% endif %}` in the for loop in my example above, does it end up adding the css to the upload button?

Comment: Yes it adds it, but it looks just like the way I have it in the question. It turns the whole widget into a button.